# Add the class in each row of the table

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on my code as I have got a list of checkboxes in the table. I have got a problem with adding the class in each row because it will only add one class in one row when I select all the checkboxes and click on a button.

Here is the checkboxes:

```
<tr class="read" data-id="236'" data-url="TTNsN1UxWXh5LzYwUjZaSlR1Qk4xZz09" data-sort="1556928960">
            <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_checkbox" name="mail_checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
            <td class="view-message dont-show">
                <div id="mail_check">Rob <myname@example.com></rob@example.com></div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message">
                <div id="mail_check">Hey!</div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_check"></div>

            </td>
            <td class="view-message text-right">
                <div id="mail_check">04 May</div>
            </td>
        </tr>


<tr class="read" data-id="235'" data-url="U21hT0hpemZRUWlwUmN3amVjMUJzQT09" data-sort="1556479689">
            <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_checkbox" name="mail_checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
            <td class="view-message dont-show">
                <div id="mail_check">Shibbir <name2@example.com></creativeartbd@gmail.com></div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message">
                <div id="mail_check">Image in body and attachement</div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_check"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></div>

            </td>
            <td class="view-message text-right">
                <div id="mail_check">28 Apr</div>
            </td>
        </tr>


<tr class="read" data-id="234'" data-url="NWpoUGcwK1lIb2tJQWlzR0grQVhEUT09" data-sort="1556479271">
            <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_checkbox" name="mail_checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
            <td class="view-message dont-show">
                <div id="mail_check">Shibbir <name2@example.com></creativeartbd@gmail.com></div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message">
                <div id="mail_check">checking message body</div>
            </td>
            <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                <div id="mail_check"></div>

            </td>
            <td class="view-message text-right">
                <div id="mail_check">28 Apr</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I have tried this:

```
$(document).on('click','#Markasunread',function() {

    alert("you are working on Markasunread now chris");

    $("#mail_checkbox1").each(function() {

        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $(".mail-check").prop("checked", false);
            $("#select_all").prop("checked", false);
            $(this).addClass("unread");

        }
    });
});
```

And I have also tried this:

```
$(document).on('click','#Markasunread',function() {


    $("#mail_checkbox1").each(function() {

        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $(".mail-check").prop("checked", false);
            $("#select_all").prop("checked", false);
            $(this).closest("tr").addClass("unread");
        }
    });
});
```

And this:

```
$(document).on('click','#Markasunread',function() {


    $("#mail_checkbox1").each(function() {

        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $(".mail-check").prop("checked", false);
            $("#select_all").prop("checked", false);
            $("#mail_checkbox1").closest("tr").addClass("unread");
        }
    });
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I select all the checkboxes and click on a button, I want to remove the class "read" and add the class "unread" in each row where the ticked checkboxes are.

Can you please show me an example how I could add the class for each row in the table where the ticked checkboxes are?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have more than one element with the same ID? That's invalid structure

Comment: Well I have each different id for each row as I want to select the rows to mark my emails as unread.

Comment: Can you please show me where do I have the elements with same ID? I have checked and each element have different ID.

Comment: All your div´s inside your td´s and all of your checkboxes

Comment: @BraveButter do you mean this one `<div id="mail_checkbox" name="mail_checkbox">`??

Comment: Yes, an ID have to be unique in the dom.

Comment: If so, can you please advise me what change I need to make so I can add the class in each row of the table where the checkbox are ticked?

Comment: Do I need to change the mail_checkbox to an id like 235, 234...etc?

Comment: You can change them however you like them to have, just don't use an ID more than once

Comment: @NicoHaase I have changed the id in the div like `<div id="236'" name="236'">` but it is still the same and I have tried `<input type="checkbox" id="236" name="236" class="mail-check" unchecked="">` but it wont add the `unread` class in each row. Any idea?

Comment: @NicoHaase it would be easier if you could show me an example how I could do this in a proper way?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xjL7qpar/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You arent allowed to use an ID more than once. So change the ID´s to a unique one. 
Also try to use better [JQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). With `"table input:checked"` you´ll get all checked input fields inside your table. Now you can loop them to get the parent `tr` and add the `unread` class.

```js
$('#actionButton').click(event => {
  let inputs = $('table input:checked').toArray();
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    $(input).closest('tr').addClass('unread');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="read" data-id="236'" data-url="TTNsN1UxWXh5LzYwUjZaSlR1Qk4xZz09" data-sort="1556928960">
      <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="1_1" name="mail_checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
      <td class="view-message dont-show">
        <div id="1_2">Rob
          <myname@example.com>
            </rob@example.com>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message">
        <div id="1_3">Hey!</div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="1_4"></div>

      </td>
      <td class="view-message text-right">
        <div id="1_5">04 May</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="read" data-id="235'" data-url="U21hT0hpemZRUWlwUmN3amVjMUJzQT09" data-sort="1556479689">
      <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="2_1" name="mail_checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox2" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
      <td class="view-message dont-show">
        <div id="2_2">Shibbir
          <name2@example.com>
            </creativeartbd@gmail.com>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message">
        <div id="2_3">Image in body and attachement</div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="2_4"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></div>

      </td>
      <td class="view-message text-right">
        <div id="2_5">28 Apr</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="read" data-id="234'" data-url="NWpoUGcwK1lIb2tJQWlzR0grQVhEUT09" data-sort="1556479271">
      <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="3_1" name="mail_checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox3" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
      <td class="view-message dont-show">
        <div id="3_2">Shibbir
          <name2@example.com>
            </creativeartbd@gmail.com>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message">
        <div id="3_3">checking message body</div>
      </td>
      <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="3_4"></div>

      </td>
      <td class="view-message text-right">
        <div id="3_5">28 Apr</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="actionButton" value="Change">
```